# Determining the WalletTransactionItem from the Wallet open app link

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app that will create Wallet Membership and Deal items.

When shown in the native Wallet app there is an open app link. I've marked it with a blue arrow below.
[image]

When my app is opened, how can I tell which item the user was viewing?

I checked the LaunchingEventArgs and ActivatedEventArgs in the App.xaml.cs, but didn't see anything that indicated why the app was being started.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `NavigationUri` property of the item.